# Spring Boot database initialization only one time

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

I have a spring boot backend application and I'm looking for a way to insert initialization data in a MySQL database but only each time the tables are created. I did that with data.sql but the data gets inserted every time the server starts. I hope my question is clear. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Use something like Flyway or Liquibase for that.

Comment: Or do a count query first to see if a table already has data or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Database initialising](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) provided by Spring Boot is meant to be used only with embedded databases. So it more or less assumes that you have to initialise the database on every start of the application.

For the proper initialising and evolution of persistent databases use [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org) or [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org)

Comment: It's probably been too long since I asked the question. But I wanted to thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's properly working for me without using Flyway.

I have a spring boot application and Mysql db. I have multiple data.*.sql files. The application.properties have the following properties.

```
## To enable reading data from multiple files
spring.datasource.data = classpath:data.*.sql

# Initialize the datasource with available DDL and DML scripts
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always 

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

One of the data.*.sql file:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO complaintPriority(name) VALUES('EMERGENCY');
INSERT IGNORE INTO complaintPriority(name) VALUES('HIGH');
INSERT IGNORE INTO complaintPriority(name) VALUES('MEDIUM');
```

Contents of the model class:

```
    @Entity
    @Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
    @Table(name = "complaintPriority", uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                    "complaintPriorityId"
            })
    })
    
    public class ComplaintPriority {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        Long complaintPriorityId;
// Other variables and methods
```